# awk condiontals for grep like things and sum of the two

Tags: linux, awk

I have a Data in a file where I have some numbers with denomination like `GB` & `TB` and i have to sum them together .

Below is file data:

```
$ cat data_in_transit| awk '/TB/{print $6}'
1.26TB
1.24TB
2.85TB
1.03TB
1.07TB
1.01TB

$ cat data_in_transit| awk '/GB/{print $6}'
962.2GB
1005GB
892.5GB
910.0GB
823.4GB
1008GB
426.4GB
168.6GB
208.1GB
511.3GB
787.5GB
448.0GB
509.6GB
496.1GB
550.7GB
```

I can calculate them individually, however i want below two to be summ'ed into one query.

Anything starting with `GB` ..

```
$ awk '/GB/{sumGB+=$6}END{printf ("%.2f\n", sumGB / 1024)}' seoul_data_in_transit
9.48
```

Anything starting with `TB` ..

```
$ awk '/TB/{sumTB+=$6}END{printf ("%.2f\n", sumTB)}' seoul_data_in_transit
8.46
```

please suggest .

Comment: please update the question to show the exected results of your new 'one query'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '$6~/GB/{s+=$6}$6~/TB/{s+=$6 * 1024}END{print s/1024,"TB"}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the current summation code generates the correct results:

```
awk '
/GB/ { sumGB+=$6 }
/TB/ { sumTB+=$6 }
END  { printf ("%.2f GB\n", sumGB / 1024)
       printf ("%.2f TB\n", sumTB)
     }
' seoul_data_in_transit
```

Which should generate:

```
9.48 GB
8.46 TB
```

Comment: @ markp-fuso, i need to sum-up these two values as well.

Comment: @kulfi please update the question with the expected result (display as GB? display as TB? display as something else?)

Comment: @ marko, it should be similar kind as the answer given by @kvantour

Answer (score 1):

this is probably way overkill, but here's an unified way to sum up sizes for anything from Kibi-bytes to Yotta-bytes down to individual bytes without hard-coding them one-by-one :

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN {
>    OFS = "\r\t\t"
>      _ = "_KMGTPEZY"
>    gsub("[^_]","&B",_)
>
>    _+=_^=__=___=____*=_____=_
>    OFMT    =  \
>    CONVFMT = "%\047"((__=-_-+-++_^_)+_*_)".f" 
>    __*=++_+!(_-=_=___=_*(_+_))
>
> } $++NF=____+=int(___^index(_____, substr($!_,length($!_)-!_))*$!_)'
> ```

```
509.6GB                        547,178,833,510
509.6MB                        547,713,187,839
550.7MB                        548,290,638,642
2.85TB                       3,681,898,777,803
168.6MB                      3,682,075,567,716
1.01KB                       3,682,075,568,750

1.03TB                       4,814,572,545,359
962.2MB                      4,815,581,485,186
448.0GB                      5,296,617,822,338
962.2GB                      6,329,772,205,390
448.0MB                      6,330,241,967,438
823.4MB                      6,331,105,364,916

823.4GB                      7,215,224,382,797
1.07KB                       7,215,224,383,892
550.7GB                      7,806,534,006,368
511.3GB                      8,355,538,200,979
892.5MB                      8,356,474,055,059
1.26TB                       9,741,858,706,056

511.3MB                      9,742,394,842,964
496.1MB                      9,742,915,041,517
1.07TB                      10,919,392,483,237
426.4GB                     11,377,235,996,990
1.24KB                      11,377,235,998,259
426.4MB                     11,377,683,111,065

208.1MB                     11,377,901,319,730
1008MB                      11,378,958,284,338
787.5GB                     12,224,529,970,738
892.5GB                     13,182,844,548,658
208.1GB                     13,406,290,222,232
1005MB                      13,407,344,041,112

910.0GB                     14,384,449,100,952
2.85KB                      14,384,449,103,870
1008GB                      15,466,780,862,462
168.6GB                     15,647,813,733,988
1.26KB                      15,647,813,735,278
787.5MB                     15,648,639,488,878

1005GB                      16,727,750,021,998
910.0MB                     16,728,704,226,158
1.03KB                      16,728,704,227,212
1.24TB                      18,092,098,645,654
496.1GB                     18,624,781,964,540
1.01TB                      19,735,288,708,593
```